# Add/Remove class FA Icon Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a nav menu using an FA Icon for the button (fa-bars) and a hidden menu panel which fades in/out when clicked. This works fine, but I would like to add/remove the icon class simultaneously.(change to fa-times) I have created a function to do this and tried to run it in the same click event, however, it doesn't seem to work. The code is below:

HTML

```
             <header>
       <a class="brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"><a/>
       <a class="js-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
       </header>
      <nav id="primary_nav">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="app.html">Silent Salesman</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Dropdown</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
 </nav><!--end primary_nav-->
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function openCloseMenu() {
 if(el.classList.contains('is-hidden')){
    fadeIn(el);
  }
  else {
    fadeOut(el);
  }
}
function alterClass(
 m.classList.add('fa-bars'); 
if (m.classList.contains('fa-bars')) {
    m.classList.remove('fa-bars');
    m.classList.add('fa-times');
  } else {
    m.classList.remove('fa-times');
    m.classList.add('fa-bars');
  }
}
var btn = document.querySelector('.js-btn');
var el = document.querySelector('#primary_nav');
var m = document.querySelector(".fa-bars");
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
openCloseMenu();
alterClass();
});
```

As it stands it works fine just running the openCloseMenu() function in the btn event, but when I try to run the alterClass() function as well, it doesn't work well. The first click changes the class on the icon but you have to click it again to open the panel (and you are clicking a close button to open it which changes back to fa-bars when it should be fa-times) the panel open/close/fade functions work fine.

Any tips welcome, Thanks

Comment: Aside: [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) has method `toggle()`.

Comment: Maybe you can have some issues because of declaring and assigning the variables after the function. You'd rather select all elements first on top of the file.

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work, Have to click the button twice, first click changes icon to X, second, opens the panel and changes it back to bars, so it's in the wrong order and needs 2 clicks, then everything works but is always in the wrong order.

Comment: Changed it to below which works at first but requires 2 clicks, then doesn't change back to bars at all, throughout.function alterClass() {
m.classList.add('fa-bars');
if (m.classList.contains('fa-bars')) {
    m.classList.remove('fa-bars');
    m.classList.add('fa-times');
  } else {
    m.classList.remove('fa-times');
    m.classList.add('fa-bars');
  }
//m.classlist.toggle('fa-times');
}                  Toggle doesnt work at all.

Comment: I added " m.classList.add('fa-bars');" at the start of the alterClass function and it's very nearly working except for it need 2 clicks, first changes icon to X, second open the panel, all others open and close the panel but the icon stays as X!

Comment: Fixed it now, just canceled the alterClass function and put the statements in the openCloseMenu function without the if/else.